# run script exactly like a user with a shell

Tags: linux, bash, centos

When I write a cronjob, service script, or daemonize a command, I often have them call a bash script or run a bash command.  The problem is that the execution of these commands behaves differently from when I run them within my login shell.  The differences come down to environment variables and many other subtleties in the way logins and shells work which I don't understand.

Is there a way to run bash commands and have them behave EXACTLY like they would if I had logged in and run them.  I need a fool proof processes where I can setup a script to run a bash command that can ideally work in these situations:

- Called in a cronjob
- Called in a service (init.d/systemd) script
- Run as a background process (like using & and nohup)
  -Configurable redirection of stderr and stdout
- Configurable users

For example, often times running: `su -c 'nohup $MY_CMD > /var/log/out.txt 2>&1 &' $MY_USER` results in errors in the application, not the shell command itself because the applications treat commands executed in a shell and non shell differently.  How do I trick the application into thinking it was invoked via a login shell?

While this methodology is certainly not production oriented, or secure, I usually find myself in last minute situations where I have to get a command to run automatically in the background (and only an hour to figure it out) as a certain user and the command itself only works if I run it manually within my shell.

I also would like to avoid the use of passing commands through an ssh connection, or invoking an ssh connection at all.  Something like `ssh $USER@127.0.0.1 '$CMD'` will require me to load ssh keys onto the machine which I would rather avoid doing.  Not sure if it matters but my main target platform is Centos 6 (would like a generalized solution for all *nix).

Bonus points if I can also capture the PID of all processes spawned by the script so I can kill them in an automated fashion later.

Comment: `bash -l` ? But there are lots of good reasons why you want your login shell to behave differently from other shells.

Comment: totally understand the whole 'this is terrible practice'.  Just wanted a quick solution when I have to get things working quickly.  For reference I'm trying to run a Django app using a runserver option.  Django searches for certain shell settings (well beyond my expertise) and when None is returned the application dies.  Using `bash -l` in this use case didn't work for me.

Comment: It took two years but I ran into a case where runuser -l <user> failed to mimic **exactly** a command run manually from the shell.  When having Apache Nifi run a python script that is running an executable the executable throws an error that does not occur when running the python script manually as a logged in user.  I guess it's back to the drawing board and wasting a couple more days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the runuser command you can use it in your init scripts etc.
You can use it in crons as well.

```
/sbin/runuser "$USER" -s /bin/sh -c "cd $BASEDIR && exec $CMD start > $STDOUTLOG 2> $STDERRLOG &"
```

You should be able to get the PID for any of the commands as well.. or just have your process write a PID file for you and cat it ( `$$` is the shell var to echo out of any of your shell processes"

Comment: When I looked up at the man page the --login option looked exactly like what I wanted.  It seems to have worked!  I've spent days worth of time fighting shell related errors for deployments that are only temporary anyways, thanks so much, this will save me tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the calling process has an SSH key set up (so as to not ask for a password), then do

`echo /path/to/some/command | ssh -t -t someuser@localhost`

From the ssh man page:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi‐
         trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```